# Android: draw figures on canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I m working on canvas. Here I just want to draw some geometric figures on canvas which may be resized according to the touch_move positions. By figures , I just meant triangle,rectangle,circle and some polygons. Is there a way to achieve this? . I haven't seen such apps which can draw these figures over canvas. So this seems to be complicated.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://www.betaful.com/2012/01/programmatic-shapes-in-android/) link.

If your application does not require a significant amount of processing or frame-rate speed (perhaps for a chess game, a snake game, or another slowly-animated application), then you should consider creating a custom View component and drawing with a Canvas in `View.onDraw()`. The most convenient aspect of doing so is that the Android framework will provide you with a pre-defined Canvas to which you will place your drawing calls.

Comment: This won't reflect my full requirement. I want to resize the figure too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can find some open-sourced out-of-the-box solutions for this if you tried a little.

If you actually want to learn something you should read the tutorials of per example;

-[Custom Views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)

-[OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html)

After doing the tutorials, you'll have 2 ways to draw basic shapes, a triangle and a circle I believe, already done.

Comment: I am not trying to implement OpenGL, I just want to draw figures like we draw lines on canvas (using canvas.drawlines()).I am not talking about view.. just draw some figures, that too on Canvas.